# How to cast a value to boolean

Tags: mysql, order-by

I need to order a query by the value of a field. If it is empty or not

I need to cast the value of the column `order_by` to a boolean and the column type is varchar

All rows where `order_by` is empty or null should be ordered last in the query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(order_by, 'boolean')
```

Comment: (1) syntax uses `AS`, not `,`, (2) no quotes on type, (3) `boolean` is not one of the few datatypes accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a concise way using [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY IFNULL(order_by,'')='';
```

or adding the [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY IF(IFNULL(order_by,'')='',1,0);
```

## UPDATE 2017-03-22 14:43 EDT

[ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) has one more suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY (order_by > '') DESC;
```

Comment: If `order_by` has a value it must be 1 or some kind of boolean.. All values with a value must be converted to the same value

Comment: fun equivalent (I think): `ORDER BY (order_by > '') DESC;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you should add that as an answer since your suggestion is very concise and function free.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Your #2 fails in my tests.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - At some level `>` and `-` are "functions".  At least in the sense that they prevent the use of an `INDEX`.

Comment: @RickJames due to nulls I guess? I didn't test ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - The `NULLs` came out first, in spite of the `-`.

Comment: Yes, correct. I should have thought of that. Removed from Rolando's answer

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
ORDER BY order_by DESC
```

since `NULL` < `''` < anything else (I think).

This probably has an advantage that

```
INDEX(order_by)
```

(or some composite index ending with `order_by`) could be used.